# The Bundle is Invalid Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, submission, mac-app-store

I've been having problems uploading my app to the app store. Every time I've uploaded the app to apple it said Invaild Binary so I tried to Validate the archived app in Xcode organizer and I'm getting this error:
This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK.

Does this mean that the app is created for the first time in a too old version of xcode? I'm currently running Xcode 4.1 but I can't remember what version the app was created in for the first time because this was one of my earlier project that I haven't completed before now.

Is there anyway to fix this without me having to recreate the whole project?

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that you should check is the Base SDK that you're building against.   To do this, select your Project in the Project Navigator and choose your target from the left pane and then choose go to the Build Settings tab.

If you have an older project that didn't require 10.6, you'll find that you will need to upgrade the Base SDK in XCode to be "Mac OS X 10.6" or "Latest Mac OS X" in order to get into the App Store.

If you still want to be able to run under 10.5, you'll basically need a separate binary, but you might be able to get away with building against the 10.6 SDK and then setting the "Mac OS X Deployment Target" to 10.5, although I'm not certain of this.  If you're only concerned with distributing via the App Store, then set this to 10.6 or the compiler default.

Comment: Setting the deployment target to the older Mac OS version should work—that’s the approach used when making iOS apps compatible with older system versions.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my answer here in case it will help others in future. I was building for 10.6, i386 and x86_64, when 10.7.1 is the current version.

It turns out that I had in fact installed 10.7.2 (to fix the screenlock bug) beta, and the compile OS version is added to Info.plist:

```
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>11C55</string>
```

which was the reason I was getting "This bundle is invalid." even though my SDK settings, and architectures were all correct.

Now, you COULD override the version by editing /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist, but I am fairly sure Apple would be 'slightly miffed' if they found out.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this same issue, today. Apparently you cannot currently submit from Mac OS 10.7.3 but must use 10.7.2 or lower (not sure how much lower :). I also had to use Application Loader v2.5.1 (235).

Hope that helps someone out there!