# Problems Submitting Mac App To Mac App Store

Tags: macos, validation, bundle, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to submit a new app to the Mac App Store but I'm getting this error every time I try to validate my bundle.

"The bundle is invalid" Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the OS."

I'm using Xcode 5.0.1 on a brand new MacBook Pro which came with Mavericks preinstalled.

What's going on? Surely this error message can't be right.

Comment: Do [people google before*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243707/lion-10-7-3-apple-is-not-currently-accepting-applications-built-with-this-versi) posting a Question at SO? ... `*` *fist result for the error message*

Comment: Thanks for responding but that link (and all the other links I've found) refer to problems when submitting from Snow Lion. I'm on the public release of Mavericks now so those fixes don't really apply.

Comment: Ok, but documenting your research in the Question is important to show that you have a unique situation. And also avoids the kind of comment I've made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't got a fix for this yet but I do have a work around..... use another Mac.

Oh wait; you haven't got another mac. Well this is what I had to do to get around it on the one it wasn't working on.

The problem seems to be that Apple don't like my particular ProductBuildVersion, which is 13A3017. I've got one of the brand new MacBook Pro 15" Retinas released Oct 2013. I'm not sure if that build version is just for these, or just for retina ones or what.

But anyway,

Use this command in terminal

sudo nano /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist

change the ProductBuildVersion from 13A3017 to 13A603 (which is another Mavericks buildVersion)

Archive the app again, (I also restarted Xcode), and resubmit it.

When you're done switch the version straight back to what it was before or anything could happen.

I've submitted a bug report to Apple so hopefully this should be fixed soon.

Comment: Actually don't reinstall Maverick, that didn't work for me. I've submitted a bug report to Apple 15365450.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the same build of Mavericks that came with my Oct 2013 rMBP. Thanks for the pointer. :)